# Unable to validate or upload CloudFormation templates in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

In CloudFormation, when I try to validate my template by clicking the "checkbox" button above the designer, or when I try to actually click the "create stack" button, both result in the same error:

> "Cannot upload this template to the S3 bucket because of an error."

This happens even when the template is the default empty template (which I assume is valid).  So I don't think this is the error I should be seeing when the syntax is wrong.

```
{
    "Parameters": {}
}
```

Any idea why this might be happening?  When I go into the S3 service in the console, it seems I can access that okay, so I don't *think* it's a permissions issue.

Googling for an answer only provides one thread on the AWS forums, but they're getting an additional permissions-related error that I'm not seeing.

I'm completely new at AWS, so please feel free to point out the obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had read-only access to S3, which was causing the error to pop up.  Once the admin made the permissions change to allow writing to S3 , I was able to do what I needed to do with CloudFormation.

Answer (score 0):

Your particular error message might be caused by an expired AWS Console session. You should try refreshing your browser and see if the error message changes.

As for the default template, it is **not** valid because it must contain at least 1 Resource. For example, when validate (using the checkbox in the designer) the default template, I get the following error message:

> Template is not valid: Template format error: At least one Resources
>   member must be defined.